# yearweek on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I extract the year and week combination from a date in SQL Server using T-SQL and have it match the MySQL `yearweek` result?

For example these MySQL queries ([Click here for MySQL SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41bcb/3)):

```
SELECT yearweek('2013-12-31');
SELECT yearweek('2014-01-01');
```

This returns `201352` for both dates. That is the expected result.

But in SQL Server...

- datepart works as expected for the year extract
- sometimes datepart does not return the expected value for `iso_week`

The MySQL result cannot be achieved with this T-SQL query...

```
SELECT datepart(year, @dt) * 100 + datepart (iso_week, @dt);
```

T-SQL versions of the MySQL queries above [(Click here for T-SQL SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b64/3):

```
SELECT datepart(year, '2013-12-31') * 100 + datepart (iso_week, '2013-12-31');
SELECT datepart(year, '2014-01-01') * 100 + datepart (iso_week, '2014-01-01');
```

The result is `201352` for the first date and `201401` for the second date.

However, this is not the expected result because...

- 2014-01-01 belongs to the **last** week of 2013
- So the expected result is `201352`

Do any of you more experienced T-SQL developers know how to extract the year/week of a given date and have this match what I see in MySQL?

I need to have the week start on Monday. This is why I am using `iso_week`. I have tested the results with `week` anyway and found the same issue. This query also produces `201401` when `201352` is expected.

```
SELECT datepart(year, '2014-01-01') * 100 + datepart (week, '2014-01-01');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the ISO_Week datepart definition at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx, you'll see the following:

> ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for
>   weeks. Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday
>   occurs...
>
> The numbering system in different countries/regions might not comply
>   with the ISO standard.

Since January 1, 2014 was a Wednesday; January 2, 2014 was the first Thursday of the year and thus week 1 of 2014 (according to ISO 8601).

Furthermore, looking at the MySQL definitions for `yearweek` and `week`, there are several mode options (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

So, I think you're going to have to write your own `yearweek` function for the week counting rule you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.yearweek(@date date)
RETURNS INT
as
 begin
    set @date = dateadd(dd,-datepart(dw,@date)+1, @date)

    return datepart(year,@date)*100 + datepart(week,@date)
 end
go

select dbo.yearweek('2013-12-31'), dbo.yearweek('2014-01-01')
```

NOTE: I haven't fully tested this code, and I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are.  This is just meant as an example of the type of process you need to follow.

Comment: @SQL.injection testing a few different dates with @chezy525's function. What would you expect for this result? `SELECT '2012-01-02' as MyDate, dbo.yearweek('2012-01-02') as yearweek_result`. I see 201153. I think you would want 201201. `SELECT '2014-01-01' as MyDate, dbo.yearweek('2014-01-01') as yearweek_result` does give the expected result 201352

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using "ISO_WEEK" as the datepart

Look at the description under the "ISO_WEEK datepart" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

using "WEEK" instead might get the desired result

Comment: there is no typo on the iso week, I want the week to start on Monday, therefore I use ISO_WEEK.

Comment: didn't say there was a typo, just that you might want a different parameter. read the description.

Answer (score 0):

TO extract YEAR, MONTH or DAY you can simply use the YEAR, MONTH and DAY function as shown in the followinf example. for any other part you have to use the DATEPART function , [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) for a detailed list of arguements you can pass to `DATEPART` function.

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [YEAR]
       , DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) [Week]
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))  +'-' 
        +   CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: how exactly "SELECT YEAR('2014-01-01') AS [YEAR]
       , DATEPART(WEEK, '2014-01-01')" is supposed to look like 2013-52? I really don't understand ... because the the 1st of January of 2014 belongs to the last week of 2013...

Comment: I have selected both values separately for demo purpose , if you want me to concatenate it as well see my update now.

Comment: did you tried your query? don't you understand the problem is that 2014-01-01 is week 52 of *2013*?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want is a week number based on the previous Monday. Is this correct? If so, iso_week is no use to you as it is based on this week's Thursday.

To get the year and week based on the previous Monday, I think you need something like the following.

```
set datefirst 1 ;

select
    SomeDate ,
    datename( weekday, SomeDate ) as [WeekdayName] , 
    datepart( weekday, SomeDate ) as [Weekday] , 
    datepart( week, SomeDate ) as [Week] ,
    datepart( iso_week, SomeDate ) as [ISO_week] ,
    dateadd( day, -( datepart( weekday, SomeDate ) - 1 ), SomeDate ) as [PreviousMonday] ,
    datepart( year, dateadd( day, -( datepart( weekday, SomeDate ) - 1 ), SomeDate ) ) as [MondayYear] ,
    datepart( week, dateadd( day, -( datepart( weekday, SomeDate ) - 1 ), SomeDate ) ) as [MondayWeek] 
from 
    dbo.DateDemo 
order by
    SomeDate ;
```

Abbreviated sample output is as follows.

```
SomeDate    PreviousMonday  MondayYear  MondayWeek
2013-12-25  2013-12-23  2013    52
2013-12-26  2013-12-23  2013    52
2013-12-27  2013-12-23  2013    52
2013-12-28  2013-12-23  2013    52
2013-12-29  2013-12-23  2013    52
2013-12-30  2013-12-30  2013    53
2013-12-31  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-01  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-02  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-03  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-04  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-05  2013-12-30  2013    53
2014-01-06  2014-01-06  2014    2
```