# Week No Of Year Starting from 1st Date of Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a requirement where the week of year starts from 1st of every Jan similar for Week of Month Starts from 1st of Every Month as shown in image

[image]

I had write below SQL code for Week of Month, but not able to go through the Week of Year

SQL Statement for Week of Month

```
  Select [Week no]=case when DATEPART(dd,Date_Value) between 1 and 7 then 1
        when DATEPART(dd,Date_Value) between 8 and 14 then 2
        when DATEPART(dd,Date_Value) between 15 and 21 then 3
        when DATEPART(dd,Date_Value) between 22 and 28 then 4
        when DATEPART(dd,Date_Value) >28 then 5
        end
        from Datecte
```

Can anybody help me in getting this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yearweek on SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096694/yearweek-on-sql-server)

Comment: Isn't this just `DATEPART(week,Date_Value)`?  The difficulty used to be that SQL Server didn't have an ISO_WEEK, but that was added.  What you describe sounds like the plain week number.  I'm not sure how the last week of December is treated, however.

Comment: try this - SELECT DAY(GetDate())/7 + 1

Comment: @BaconBits . . . ISO weeks are considerably more complicated because they start on Mondays.  You can read excruciating detail on Wikipedia (and elsewhere):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler method for the week of the month is to do:

```
select (day(date_value) + 6) / 7 as weekOfMonth
```

The `+ 6` is because `day()` returns values between 1 and 7, and the weeks are numbered starting with 1.  Note that SQL Server does integer division so the result is an integer.

You can do something similar for the year:

```
select (datediff(day, cast(datename(year, date_value) + '-01-01' as date), date_value) + 7) / 7 as weekOfYear
```

The date difference gets the day number of the year.  The `+ 7` is just so the counting starts at 1 rather than 0.

Finally, if these values are important for you, then you can add computed columns to the table in question:

```
alter table t add WeekOfMonday as ((day(date_value) + 6) / 7)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both solutions work for Week of Month and Week of Year works

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATEPART`, `DATEADD` & `DATEDIFF` functions this can be achieved.

```
SELECT date, 
DATEPART(wk, date) AS WeekofYear,
DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date), 0), date) +1 AS WeekofMonth,
FROM Datecte
```

Comment: Thanks matt, the solution you had given is certainly not the requirement as it taking the Monday as the start of week. I don't need the day to be the start of week , 1st date irrespective of day should be the starting of week.